# Exception: The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My friend send me her flutter code, and she uses Windows. However, when I unzip it on my Mac and try to run it, I get this error:

```
Exception: The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.
```

Even though I can run my Flutter project without any errors -- how could I fix this?

I tried to run the following command but it did not work:

```
sudo xattr -c -r  <project_folder>
```

Comment: Try a flutter clean and flutter pub get.

Comment: thank you for your help, flutter clean cange some files and to have my username but I still have the same error